# How to get data from database and into listview.builder

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get data from Firebase RTDB and then display them as a list using Listview.builder.

This worked well before, however I have added a new node into my database to have it be more stuctured. The problem is, inspite of there being data, it's showing up as empty when I try to retrieve it.

**Database before:** [image]

**Database Now:** [image]

**Code:**

```
Future<List> getParentDetails() async {
    schoolName = await getSchoolName();
    databaseReference
        .child("users")
        .child(schoolName.toString()) // (newly added)
        .child("parents")
        .onValue
        .listen(
      (event) {
        if (event.snapshot.exists) {
          setState(
            () {
              var value = event.snapshot.value;
              parentList = Map.from(value)
                  .values
                  .map((e) => Parents.fromJson(Map.from(e)))
                  .toList();
            },
          );
        } else {
          print("No Data Exists");
        }
      },
    );
    return parentList;
  }
```

**UI Code:**

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: parentList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
    final Parents parents = parentList[index];
    final String parentEmail = parents.email;
    final String parentName = parents.name;
    final String parentPhone = parents.phone;
    
    // final String parentUID = parents.uid;
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Card(
        elevation: 0.2,
        child: ExpansionTile(
          // collapsedBackgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          title: Text(
            parentName.toUpperCase(),
            style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(
              fontSize: 12,
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  parentEmail,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(fontSize: 12),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),
                Text(
                  parentPhone,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(fontSize: 12),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

**New Edit:**

```
getSchoolName() async {
    // ignore: unused_local_variable
    final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
    User user = auth.currentUser;
    String adminUID = user.uid.toString();
    print("Getting School Name");
    databaseReference.child("users").child("admin").child(adminUID).once().then(
      (DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        setState(() {
          schlName = snapshot.value["school"];
          print(schlName); //  (Prints - Highway Secondary School)
        });
      },
    );
    return await schlName;
  }

  Future<List> getParentDetails() async {
    schoolName = await getSchoolName();
    databaseReference
        .child("users")
        .child("Highway Secondary School")
        .child("parents")
        .onValue
        .listen(
      (event) {
        if (event.snapshot.exists) {
          setState(
            () {
              var value = event.snapshot.value;
              print(value); //  (See print value below)
              parentList = Map.from(value)
                  .values
                  .map((e) => Parents.fromJson(Map.from(e)))
                  .toList();
            },
          );
        } else {
          print("No Data Exists");
        }
      },
    );
    return parentList;
  }
```

Output:

> {L9LnmRTZJgVJWjNhrcTqoRdMlas2: {driver: Locate the driver: , phone: ********, school: Highway Secondary School, name: Parent One, user uid: L9LnmRTZJgVJWjNhrcTqoRdMlas2, email: **********@gmail.com}, Z9nHn3HZ3MZqgS7RsKsFiofD4ty2: {driver: Locate the driver: , phone: ********, school: Highway Secondary School, name: Parent Two, user uid: Z9nHn3HZ3MZqgS7RsKsFiofD4ty2, email: ***********@gmail.com}}

Edit 2:

```
 Future<List> getParentDetails() async {
    schoolName = await getSchoolName();
    print(schoolName);  (Prints - null)

    var ref = databaseReference.child("users/$schoolName/parents");
    var snapshot = await ref.get();
    if (snapshot.exists) {
      setState(() {
        var value = snapshot.value;
        parentList = Map.from(value)
            .values
            .map((e) => Parents.fromJson(Map.from(e)))
            .toList();
      });
    } else {
      print("No Data Exists");
    }
    return parentList;
}
```

With newly added line of code above, the code doesn't get any data from the database (from the current database).

Without the newly added line of code, I get data from the old database without any issues.

The intention of the new database is to be more organized.

Comment: are you sure the value in `schoolName` is correct?

Comment: value of key must be same which is you are using in RTDB

Comment: @MeetPatel value of key is the same. Like I stated above, code works perfectly with the old database but doesn't work with the new one. Only thing I changed is what is shown above. When I put another key, an error occurs, but with how it currently is, no error, just empty.

Comment: @IvoBeckers Yes, I print it out each time to make sure the correct name is being retrieved from the other method. When I hard code the name of the school "Highway Secondary School" into the child, I still get the same results, no data.

Comment: If you print it out already, show *that* code and its output in your question please, so that we can also see it. --- Even better would be to use a hard-coded value for the school name. If you can reproduce it with that, show *that* code in your question, and we can focus on other potential causes. --- If you `print(event.snapshot.value)`, what does it output? Can you show both that updated code and its output in your question?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi Mr. Frank, I have updated the question and included both codes and output of print(event.snapshot.value) above (New Edit)

Answer (score 0):

This will not work:

```
Future<List> getParentDetails() async {
  schoolName = await getSchoolName();
  databaseReference
      .child("users")
      .child("Highway Secondary School")
      .child("parents")
      .onValue
      .listen(
    (event) {
      if (event.snapshot.exists) {
        setState(
          () {
            var value = event.snapshot.value;
            print(value); //  (See print value below)
            parentList = Map.from(value)
                .values
                .map((e) => Parents.fromJson(Map.from(e)))
                .toList();
          },
        );
      } else {
        print("No Data Exists");
      }
    },
  );
  return parentList;
}
```

Calling `listen` starts an asynchronous process, but your main code continues to run. So your `return parentList` runs before the `parentList = Map.from(value)` is ever called. Adding some more print statements will show that in the order of they are output.

You also return a `Future`, which you can do only once, while `listen` can be called many times. If you only get about the current value, you should use `get()` instead of `listen` as shown in the documentation on [reading data once](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/read-and-write#read-data-once).

With that, the code would look something like:

```
Future<List> getParentDetails() async {
  schoolName = await getSchoolName();
  var ref = databaseReference.child("users/Highway Secondary School/parents");
  var snapshot = await ref.get();
  if (snapshot.exists) {
    setState(
      () {
        var value = snapshot.value;
        parentList = Map.from(value)
            .values
            .map((e) => Parents.fromJson(Map.from(e)))
            .toList();
      },
    );
  } else {
    print("No Data Exists");
  }
  return parentList;
}
```

---

**Update: to also fix `getSchoolName`** it's important to not mix `then` with `async`/`await`, but use one or the other only.

```
getSchoolName() async {
  final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  User user = auth.currentUser;
  String adminUID = user.uid.toString();

  var snapshot = databaseReference.child("users/admin").child(adminUID).get();
  schlName = snapshot.value["school"];
  setState(() {});

  return schlName;
}
```

Comment: I understand, I've tried the above code, works as intended with "Highway Secondary School" hard coded into it, however I'm trying to get the school name using the getSchoolName() method, and passing its value as a child. This still doesn't work. Please check "Edit 2"

Comment: Yeah, you will have to apply the same fix that I applied to `getParentDetails` for you to `getSchoolName` too. I added an update for it to my answer too, but recommend taking some time to learn more about asynchronous code, futures and streams before continuing on with your app, as understanding all these concepts is key to not running into synchronization problems such as these.